# ContentType as Gzip does not work?

Tags: .net, ajax, json, gzip

I was using application/json as a contenttype of the data that is sent. But when I change the contenttype as gzip, the client(browser) does not handle the response that is sent from server. Is there anything that I can do to solve this problem ? Should I do more than just changing contentype ?

The Headers that is received from the server.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Sat, 23 Jul 2011 02:30:54 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Accept-Encoding: : gzip,deflate
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: gzip; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1667
Connection: Close
```

Comment: You should post the part of your source code that's responsible for all the gzipping.

Answer (score 3):

You want your content-encoding header to be gzip, leave your content-type whatever it was.